# React-autosuggest. Prevent the transition to the beginning when the last element of the list is reached using the down key

Tags: reactjs, autosuggest

I'm using the http://react-autosuggest.js.org/ component.

When the last element is reached by pressing the button down, I return to the top of the list.

Is there a solution to prevent the cursor from moving to the beginning?

I will be grateful for the advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the plugin to react-autowhatever. 
It allows you to achieve any design and behavior. 
https://github.com/moroshko/react-autowhatever